# VS show controlname "does not exist in the current context", but it builds fine

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

When I have added a control in the XAML, Visual Studio keeps complaining about the control name in the C# with `The name 'mycontrolname' does not exist in the current context`. It still builds and runs just fine, so it is just an annoyance. It stops IntelliSense from working on that name too.

The errors go away if I close and reopen the whole solution, but is there anything better I can do?

Answer (score 1):

Start Visual Studio, Go to Edit -> Intellisense -> Refresh Remote references. Check below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: VS 2010 equivalent is Project -> Rescan Solution.. Let me know if this works.. I'll update the answer accordingly..

Comment: I use VS2015, and there is no Project -> Rescan Solution either.

Comment: Try opening the solution path in Explorer and delete the `.suo` file